# como usar el WHERE en un SNAPSHOT.DATA.WHERE

Tags: firebase, flutter, url, dart, real-time

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo el siguiente código(imagen), y solo agrego los ITEMS que son diferentes al correo del usuario comparado al correo en el registro, actualmente lo hago con un IF pero ya obteniendo todos los datos de la BD, no quiero hacerlo de esa forma, quiero ahorrar peticiones a firebase y deseo obtenerlos ya desde la consulta a la BD, como puedo hacerlo?...me dijeron que con un where en el snapshot, pero no encuentro un ejemplo claro. gracias.

Comment: que usas Firebase Realtime o Firestore?

Comment: realtime y es una sola tabla

Comment: hay mucha documentación en la web sobre Flutter + Firebase, busca bien y dinos cual es tu duda despues de buscar

Comment: ya busqué, pero no encuwentro la forma de hacer un where desde antes de hacer la petición a la BD, para que no me traiga todos los registros y solo sean los registros donde el campo X sea = al valor X que necesito, porque encontré unos métodos, pero no haciéndolo como lo tengo en el ejemplo con llamadas GET a la URL